# Getting "Windows Script Host" : Error code 800A03F6, Microsoft JScript compilation error, when executing module after using npm link

Tags: node.js, wsh

Windows Script Host prompts this error when trying to run your node cli

[image]

**Steps to reproduce issue:**

1. Create simple node 'Hello world' project
2. use `npm link` to link the package.
3. Try running the module using `<packagename>`.

Comment: JScript is not modern JavaScript, so don’t expect to be able to use NodeJS in the Windows Scripting Host.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to run the module using this link at the to of my index.js(main) file `#!/usr/bin/env node`.

> In the case of Node.js, this line is used to specify that the script
> should be run with the Node.js interpreter. When you run a script with
> this shebang, the shell looks for the node executable in the system's
> $PATH environment variable and uses it to execute the script.
>
> - answered ChatGPT

Comment: Thanks for your honesty at least, but using chatGPT is not allowed on StackOverflow.

Comment: I was not aware of that. I just posted it so that it might help someone.